# Configuring options for middleware

Tags: asp.net-core, middleware

Looking on different libraries and even Microsoft code I've noticed two different ways of configuring options in code:

in `ConfigureServices` it can be done when registering `DependencyInjection`:

```
services.AddMvc(options => { });
```

or in `Configure`

```
app.UseStaticFiles(
     new StaticFileOptions
     {
        ServeUnknownFileTypes = true
     });
```

I tried to find out, which way use for which purpose and still don't know, assuming that creating your own middleware and registering both DI and usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting issue you have found.

Looking into the source code i have found the following:

All the middleware registrations are an overload of this [UseMiddleware](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/b7d9e11a8442994cf5c4b8292d72b1efbd7e5a42/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Extensions/UseMiddlewareExtensions.cs#L20) function, which is an overload of `IApplicationBuilder Use(Func<RequestDelegate, RequestDelegate> middleware);`.

In these overloads you can specify hard your own parameters for the middle-ware. Say you have a few strings in the constructor, the DI container will not be able to resolve this.

If the parameters aren't set though, it does fallback to the `IServiceProvider` to resolve the specific type. see extension class: `Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities` (inside: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll`)

## Tips

As for best practice think about the following (my opinion though):

- Try to avoid using simple types in constructor but use an Options class.
- for IOptions use `services.Configure<>()` as here you can specify options from a ConfigSection => appsettings.
- As for Services: be aware that middleware is a singleton! so adding a transient Service, will only be resolved once for this middleware!

I think best practise is to: Register Middleware AND its dependencies as singletons in IOC on startup. then resolve it yourself and add it yourself with the method `App.Use([yourDelegate])`.

The advantage of this method is it is easilier understandable than use the hidden microsoft code + Microsoft recently published an upgrade to the DI container to check if the scopes of your registrations match properly (and warn you if not).

This tool basically does: it checks if a dependency of a service has a smaller scope then the service itself: say service is scope: `Singleton` and the dependency is scope `Transient`. this means that if `Singleton` is resolved `Transient` is also resolved for this singleton and thus not resolved again on next usage of this singleton. (so its a hidden singleton usage).

Comment: I'm still confused, as you are saying options should be configured in services, instead of adding them in Use...method.

Comment: @Marcin yes, If you look at whats happening underwater its better to add it in Configured services. adding it in the Use is kind of a Microsoft allowed hack. I wouldn't be surprised if they might remove it later. Also this gives you the option to Resolve this `IOptions<class>` anywhere else in code.

Comment: Note that although you're correct middleware are created only once, their Invoke method also supports DI. So if you have per-request services you need to send to middleware, you can inject them via the Invoke method.